# Delete from a MYSQL subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I'd like to delete all the records in a table matching the subquery as so:

```
delete from device where clientMac =   (select * from device  where clientMac = '80:d6:05:02:1d:b9');
```

I'm getting this error:

> Error Code 1241: Operand should contain 1 column

I want to also avoid:

> Error 1093: You can't specify target table for update in FROM clause

Answer (score 2):

If i understand your query right then your query doesn't require subquery. Please look this:

DELETE FROM device WHERE clientMac IN (SELECT clientMac FROM device where clientMac='80:d6:05:02:1d:b9')

Is equivalant to :

DELETE FROM device WHERE clientMac='80:d6:05:02:1d:b9';

I think you wanted to achieve something else. Please confirm.

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to mismatch of columns. Your select query must only return column **clientMac** and also if there are multiple result expected then use IN Query like below

```
delete from device where clientMac IN (select clientMac from device where clientMac = '80:d6:05:02:1d:b9');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
delete from device 
where clientMac in (
      select * from 
      (select clientMac  from device where clientMac = '80:d6:05:02:1d:b9')as t
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Here id field is your primary key of table.

```
delete 
from device 
where id in (select * 
             from (select id 
                   from device 
                   where FIND_IN_SET(clientMac,'80:d6:05:02:1d:b9')) 
             as t1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use IN

```
DELETE FROM device WHERE clientMac IN (SELECT clientMac FROM device where clientMac='80:d6:05:02:1d:b9')
```

Comment: It will not work as there are muliple coulmns returned when you call SELECT * and you are checking clientMac with all columns